# If $E \subset [0,1]$ satisfies, for any $I \subset [0,1]$, $m(E \cap I) \geq \frac{1}{2}m(I)$, then $m(E)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure

If $E \subset [0,1]$ satisfies, for any $I \subset [0,1]$, $m(E \cap I) \geq \frac{1}{2}m(I)$, then $m(E)=1.$

I'm aware this post exists elsewhere, say, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840857/me%E2%88%A9i%E2%89%A5%CE%B1mi-for-all-intervals-i%E2%8A%820-1-prove-that-me-1)
 but what I don't understand is why we cannot choose something like $I = ([0,1]) \cap E^c$ and note that
$$m(E \cap E^c) = m(\emptyset) = 0 \geq \frac{1}{2}m([0,1] \cap E^c)$$

and therefore $m([0,1] \cap E^c) =0$, so $m(E) = 1$.

What's wrong with such a simple argument?

Comment: Your $I$ is very likely not an interval.

Comment: @JohnMa Is $I$ supposed to be an interval?

Comment: @JohnMa Ah, I see it is in the other post, mine does not. See: http://www.math.utoronto.ca/almut/MAT1000/MAT1000-final2011.pdf

Comment: Your method works if $I$ can be anything.

Comment: The usual version of this question is: if $E \subseteq [0,1]$ is **measurable** and for every **interval** $I \subseteq [0,1]$, $m(E \cap I) \ge \frac{1}{2} m(I)$, then $m(E) = 1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Duly noted. Odd that it appears this way in the given source.

Comment: $I$ is often used to denote an interval, but generally not for other sets, so it's likely the author forgot to write "interval".

Comment: @RobertIsrael In the case of an interval, does it suffice to use inner-regularity to show that for any interval $I \subset E^c$ we have $$m(E \cap I \cap [0,1]) = 0 \geq \frac{1}{2} m(I \cap [0,1])$$ to conclude that $m(E^c) = 0$, since it is the limit of such $m(I)$'s?

Comment: @RobertIsrael or must more be done?

Comment: It does not suffice: it's quite possible that $E^c$ contains no intervals.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ah of course. Could we take the outer measure instead?